# Adding Outlets for a Stove and Refrigerator in my Basement

Tags: receptacle, electrical-panel, refrigerator, stove

Does my panel have enough amperage and space for adding two outlets for a stove and refrigerator in my basement? Thanks for your help in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post how many square feet your house is, how many kitchen small appliance branch circuits it has, and how much power your large appliances (if electric) pull? (i.e. a heat pump, electric central heat, or air conditioner, as well as your water heater, existing stove/range, and dryer)

Comment: Looks like a 200 Amp panel - start counting how many amps your installed circuits are using. That tells you how much Amperage you are using (200A - Using x Amps) equals available - then you would need to rearrange and change a breaker or two to get the space you need. My guess is you will find yourself maxed out in Amperage. As a range will use at least 40 AMPS to 50 AMPS.

Comment: Are there 2 slots open on each side of the bottom or 1? If you have a smart meter ask the power company what your peak demand is this will provide a quick answer if your peak demand is 150 or less sure it can be done. Most homes that I have checked on 150+ services are well below the panel rating. I think other than all electric base board ,water heater oven,,,, homes most homes have been less than 60-70% on the all electric I have seen a panel at 90%. If you don't have a smart meter a amp clamp meter can tell you what your current draw on each leg is.

Answer (score 1):

Not without some rearranging, unless your stove is only 110V  (which is more like a hotplate or electric grill, or a gas stove).  If that is the case you can put a 2 new breakers on the bottom row to supply 2 new 120V circuits.

In order to have a 220V electric range/oven you need a 240V breaker that spans both phases.  A 240V breaker is double height,  so you need to remove a breaker from the bottom left or bottom right to make space.   One way is remove the 2 on the bottom left, and combine them into a single tandem breaker (2 circuits that take up one space, such as you have in the bottom right).  That would leave you room (2 slots) for a 240V on the left, and you'd have a remaining slot on the right for the new 120V circuit.

Edit:
200 amp service is more than enough for almost any house.  You can put circuit breakers that add up to more than 200 it’s not a problem.  If you ever used more than 200 amps in total your main breaker would flip and at that point you’d know your limits and live with it, or decide to upgrade the service.   Realistically that probably won’t be an issue unless your oven was on cleaning cycle, with an AC running or a couple space heaters going, clothes dryer, curling iron, hot water heater, and someone welding while blow drying their hair!

Comment: That takes care of space, but not amperage?

Comment: I would not worry too much about it unless you are planning to upgrade your panel.  I edited my answer to address amps

Answer (score 0):

The diagram shows a 30-*space* panel, and the picture shows 26 *spaces* in use.

So **yes**, you can fit a 1-space 120V breaker for a fridge, as well as whatever your range requires: 1-space 120V for a gas range or 2-space 240V breaker for an electric.

This will almost wipe out your panel's spaces, which is not a good place to be.  You see one "double-stuff" breaker where two 120V circuits are crammed into one "space". Your panel can do that in the bottom 4 rows) but most newer circuits require AFCI or GFCI, and those *can't exist in double-stuff*.

Keep in mind if you are installing anything like a kitchenette where food prep might happen, then *kitchen rules* apply, and there's quite a large requirement for circuits, including two *dedicated* countertop circuits.  If your range is gas, you're in luck: it can tap a countertop circuit.  (only ranges and clocks can do so).   If it's electric, it will bogart 2 spaces *just for it*, leaving you pinched for the remaining mandatory circuits - you may be forced to deploy double-stuff breakers or a subpanel.